# mac osx lion samba3 installed, not visible in windows 7 network list

Tags: mac-osx, samba, server-message-block

so here is the thing.
i have installed samba3 on my macbook pro (osx lion) if i go to my windows pc and i put `\\<ip of mac>` into explorer bar this works i get the list of shared files.

But now i need my mac to show up into the list that windows makes of all the systems connected to network.

now you will ask why do you want this? I want this because ultimatily i want to browse my macbook through my Eminent hdMedia RT2 and i noticed this device only shows the devices which show up in the windows network list. in windows explorer.

So my question is: how can i let windows know to see my mac, i am guessing through the smb.conf?????

or even better: if you know it? how to add a device manually to Eminent hdMedia RT2???

any help is much appreciated.

PS. I also have a ubuntu 11.10 machine with smb but this one does get shown in the network list. i used Webmin to configure smb for my ubuntu system.